# Alternative to CRON time scheduling schema?

Tags: cron, schedule

I'm looking for time schedule schemas other than cron, I mean is there another standard for schedule than e.g. "0 0 0/1 1/1 * ? *" which is in cron?

I know cron is a well experienced solution, but I'm looking for other approaches of storing dates and periods.

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to solve so people can better help you to find a solution.  There are many ways to do do things like cron does depending on if you need something run at regular intervals (like cron), or just one-offs, or want to run things at the system level, or want something for desktop, or want something for an application.